# “Invalid provider specified” while creating provider-hosted SharePoint Add-ins

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-online, provider-hosted

Working to create provider-hosted SharePoint Add-ins for SharePoint online using VS2015 having installed all perquisites using [MSDN tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142381.aspx) facing an error pop message “Invalid provider specified”, I have googled it and found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3096080) on Microsoft Official Support site as it is a known issue and workarounds are mentioned there to solve it, I have tried these but still facing the same error message.
If anyone have encounter this issue or have any idea to get rid of it.[image] this error message pop up appears above the credentials window after selecting New Project => SharePoint Add-in from VS2015 start menu for reference screen shot is given.

Comment: Try to add the login.microsoftonline.com under Trusted Site on IE.

Comment: @Max, I have tried after adding in IE but didn't work, bay the way I couldn't understand why adding in IE as I facing this error while creating SharePoint Add-in.

Comment: The error refer to login.microsoftonline.com for the OAuth authentication and I supposed there's problem with the credentials.